# How to execute .sql file using powershell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, powershell-module

I have a .`sql` file. I am trying to pass connection string details through a Powershell script and invoke an `.sql` file.

I was searching and came up with a cmdlet related to `Invoke-sqlcmd`. While I was trying to find a module corresponding to SQL, I did not find any one in my machine.

Should I install anything in my machine (the machine already has SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2) to get the modules or is there any easy way to execute `.sql` files using Powershell?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try to see if SQL snap-ins are present:

```
get-pssnapin -Registered

Name        : SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes various SQL Server cmdlets.

Name        : SqlServerProviderSnapin100
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : SQL Server Provider
```

If so

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 # here lives Invoke-SqlCmd
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

then you can do something like this:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "c:\mysqlfile.sql" -serverinstance "servername\serverinstance" -database "mydatabase" # the parameter -database can be omitted based on what your sql script does.
```

Comment: An addition to this for SQL Server 2012, use SqlServerCmdletSnapin110 and SqlServerProviderSnapin110 for registering.

Comment: @M.C.Rohith: Thanks for your value addition. Really an useful information

Comment: Just an FYI as im sure many people stumble onto the question.With the newer versions of SQL they have sqlps. you can just add Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking to your script

Comment: @workabyte Have you read this answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10923160/520612 ??  ;)

Comment: @CB. lol nope thats why i put the comment here, this answer is at the top and has a lot of votes so i added the comment somewhere people would see it unlike the answer below. Thanks for pointing it out lmao

Comment: PSA: For newer versions of PowerShell, you may want to try `Imoprt-Module SQLPS` instead, or `Get-Module -List | ? Name -eq sqlps` to see if you have one or more SQLPS modules available to import.

Comment: I have "Microsoft SQL Server 2019" installed, and find that you do NOT refer to 'SQLPS' anymore, instead, to import the module: 
Import-Module sqlserver -DisableNameChecking

Answer (score 45):

Quoting from [Import the SQLPS Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx) on MSDN,

> The recommended way to manage SQL Server from PowerShell is to import
>   the sqlps module into a Windows PowerShell 2.0 environment.

So, yes, you could use the `Add-PSSnapin` approach detailed by Christian, but it is also useful to appreciate the recommended sqlps module approach.

The simplest case assumes you have SQL Server 2012: **sqlps** is included in the installation so you simply load the module like any other (typically in your [profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) via `Import-Module sqlps`. You can check if the module is available on your system with `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

If you do not have SQL Server 2012, then all you need do is download the **sqlps** module into your modules directory so Get-Module/Import-Module will find it. Curiously, Microsoft does *not* make this module available for download! However, Chad Miller has kindly packaged up the requisite pieces and provided [this module download](http://sev17.com/2010/07/making-a-sqlps-module/). Unzip it under your ...Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules directory and proceed with the import.

It is interesting to note that the module approach and the snapin approach are not identical. If you load the snapins then run `Get-PSSnapin` (*without* the -Registered parameter, to show only what you have loaded) you will see the SQL snapins. If, on the other hand, you load the sqlps module `Get-PSSnapin` will not show the snapins loaded, so the various blog entries that test for the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet by only examining snapins could be giving a false negative result.

**2012.10.06 Update**

For the complete story on the sqlps module vs. the sqlps mini-shell vs. SQL Server snap-ins, take a look at my two-part mini-series [Practical PowerShell for SQL Server Developers and DBAs](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/practical-powershell-for-sql-server-developers-and-dbas-%E2%80%93-part-1/) recently published on Simple-Talk.com where I have, according to one reader's comment, successfully "de-confused" the issue. :-)

Comment: Note that you can now [download the SQLPS module from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580) ; with `PowerShellTools.msi`, there are a x86 and a x64 version.

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvalable` >> a correct command is `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

Comment: To use PowerShell with SSMS 17 or later, install it from the PowerShell Gallery with `Install-Module -Name SqlServer`

Answer (score 7):

```
if(Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS") { #Sql Server 2012
    Import-Module SqlPs -DisableNameChecking
    C: # Switch back from SqlServer
} else { #Sql Server 2008
    Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 # here live Invoke-SqlCmd
}

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "MySqlScript.sql" -ServerInstance "Database name" -ErrorAction 'Stop' -Verbose -QueryTimeout 1800 # 30min
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a light weight approach for simple scripts that requires no additional tools / setup / PowerShell add-ons.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connectionStringGoesHere
$conn.Open()
$content = Get-Content $scriptFileNameGoesHere
$cmds = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$cmd = ""
$content | foreach {
    if ($_.Trim() -eq "GO") { $cmds.Add($cmd); $cmd = "" } 
    else { $cmd =  $cmd + $_ +"`r`n" }
}
$cmds | foreach {
    $sc = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $sc.CommandText = $_
    $sc.Connection = $conn
    $sc.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that I have in my PowerShell profile for loading SQL snapins:

```
function Load-SQL-Server-Snap-Ins
{
    try 
    {
        $sqlpsreg="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps"

        if (!(Test-Path $sqlpsreg -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"))
        {
            throw "SQL Server Powershell is not installed yet (part of SQLServer installation)."
        }

        $item = Get-ItemProperty $sqlpsreg
        $sqlpsPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($item.Path)

        $assemblyList = @(
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo ",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Collector",
            "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.CollectorEnum"
        )

        foreach ($assembly in $assemblyList)
        { 
            $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($assembly) 
            if ($assembly -eq $null)
                { Write-Host "`t`t($MyInvocation.InvocationName): Could not load $assembly" }
        }

        Set-Variable -scope Global -name SqlServerMaximumChildItems -Value 0
        Set-Variable -scope Global -name SqlServerConnectionTimeout -Value 30
        Set-Variable -scope Global -name SqlServerIncludeSystemObjects -Value $false
        Set-Variable -scope Global -name SqlServerMaximumTabCompletion -Value 1000

        Push-Location

         if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerProviderSnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
        { 
            cd $sqlpsPath

            Add-PsSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100 -ErrorAction Stop
            Add-PsSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 -ErrorAction Stop
            Update-TypeData -PrependPath SQLProvider.Types.ps1xml
            Update-FormatData -PrependPath SQLProvider.Format.ps1xml
        }
    } 

    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "`t`t$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_" 
    }

    finally
    {
        Pop-Location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with 2008 Server 2008 and 2008 R2

```
Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerCmdletSnapin100, SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

with 2012 and 2014

```
Push-Location
Import-Module -Name SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database MyDatabase -Query "exec dbo.sp_executesql N'$(Get-Content "c:\my.sql")'"`

Comment: this function errors, if the SQL in the file contains quotes