# Cannot run Invoke-Sqlcmd in a PS1 file but can on the console

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I'm currently on a machine with SQL server 2008 and according to this question ([How to execute .sql file using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894688/how-to-execute-sql-file-using-powershell)), I've installed the powershell snapins to interact with SQL server.

The problem is that now I have it installed, I can run Invoke-Sqlcmd from the command line like this.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile "myTestFile.sql" -serverinstance '.\sql2008';
```

but if I put that line inside a PS1 file run and try to run it like so

```
powershell ./runSQLscript.ps1
```

I get this error

> The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At D:\TEMP\powershellTests\runSQLscript.ps1:1 char:14
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd <<<<  -inputfile "myTestFile.sql" -serverinstance '.\sql2008';
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: In your PS1 file you would also need to `Add-PSSnapin` the SQL snapins so PowerShell knows to load this function before it's used.

Comment: @Bluecakes - yes that fixed it! Please add that as the answer. Okay so add-snapins are not global commands and relevant to the context it's run in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your PS1 you need to `Add-PSSnapin` and load the SQL snapins.

Each Powershell window is a new environment in which modules and snapins are not yet loaded.