# Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I want to create a table using .sql file through PowerShell.

Running following in Windows PowerShell ISE as Administrator:

```psh
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'D:\SQL Scripts\test.sql' -ServerInstance 'localhost\MSSQLSERVER' -Database 'Test'
```

But this is giving following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The 
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Could any one please guide to fix this.

I have already refereed [execute .sql using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894688/how-to-execute-sql-file-using-powershell)

Answer (score 8):

I myself got the answer after I manually tried to connect the SQL Server Management Studio.

There it's taking server name as localhost. No need to mention the instance name, it's connecting to default instance.

This worked:

```psh
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'D:\SQL Scripts\test.sql' -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'Test'
```

Comment: it is worth mentioning that -ServerInstance can be set to another server and/or a non default named instance:

<HOSTNAME>/<INSTANCENAME>