# Executing .SQL file from cmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, localdb

i want to execute a .sql file from cmd. Here's my command :

---

`sqlcmd -e -S "(localdb)\myDB" -i "C:\PathToMyFile\File.sql" -U user -P password`

---

Here's my errors :

---

[image: Errors]

---

Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 is installed. Someone knows what I've done wrong? Thx.

Comment: can you go to sql server configuration manager and make sure SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is running?

in addition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953100/invoke-sqlcmd-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-esta

Comment: It's never a good idea to post an image of your errors. You'll do much better here to put the error **text** here, even if you have to re-type it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn why it is not good idea?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Lot's of people will never see that image or choose not to bother with it. Using an image instead of text limits the number of people who might have helped you.

Comment: network issue    .

Comment: It also won't come up in google searches, so the overall quality of StackOverflow as a resource is lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong server name:

```
sqlcmd -e -S "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" -d MyDB -i "C:\PathToMyFile\File.sql" -U user -P password
```

or with Integrated Authentication:

```
sqlcmd -e -S "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" -d MyDB -i "C:\PathToMyFile\File.sql" -E
```

Comment: Yea that's it ! Thx :)