# SQL Job Step to Compare File Names

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, file-comparison

I have a folder which gets populated automatically with text files with names of SQL functions.  I have another folder at a set location that has all the actual SQL functions in them.

What I'm trying to do is come up with a SQL job that will look at the folder of text file names, compare the names of those files to the actual function file names, and then run any of the function files where the names match.

I have the first step where it checks for any files existing in the text file folder but I cant seem to find any syntax on how to compare file names in a given directory.  Could anyone point me in the right direction or am I just spinning my wheels on something that's not really possible?

Answer (score 2):

Powershell can help. Howewer, It may be painful if you not familiar with PS yet.

1. It's possible to run PS script as a step of SQL Agent job.
2. Comparison of two folder contents starts with `Compare-Object` cmdlet: http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/11996/20922.aspx
3. Of course, sql code can be executed from the PS using `invoke-sqlcmd`: [How to execute .sql file using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894688/how-to-execute-sql-file-using-powershell)

Hope it helps!