# How to restore schema on the Azure SQL Server Databases using PowerShell script?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, schema, restore

I have created a sql server, deployed elastic pool on that server and am able to create multiple databases in that elastic pool as per this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/257739/197860. Now my purpose of uploading this question is..I want to restore only schema and then later data on to those
created azure sql databases using PowerShell Script. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: what's the database schema do you want to restore from?

Answer (score 0):

If you want restore the schema from local SQL server to Azure SQL database in the Elastic Pool, you could use the tool [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).

DMA supports oly migrate the schema:

[image]

If you want restore the schema between Azure SQL database, you could use SSMS [Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15). You can use the **Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard** to create scripts for transferring a database between instances of the SQL Server Database Engine or Azure SQL Database.

Right click database--Generate Script:

[image]

[image]

Then you could using PowerShell to run the SQL script.

Reference:

1. [How to execute .sql file using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894688/how-to-execute-sql-file-using-powershell)
2. [How to execute SQL Script using windows powershell(using
   invoke-sqlcmd or any if)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b811c1b7-1fda-4027-ab97-9ecb1fabff36/how-to-execute-sql-script-using-windows-powershellusing-invokesqlcmd-or-any-if?forum=sqlsecurity)

I have a question, since you need to restore the schema and then later data to those created Azure SQL databases, why don't you import the backup file like .bacpac files to create database in that Azure SQL server with PowerShell directly?

Please reference these tutorial:

- [Export a database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)
- [Powershell:Import a BACPAC file to a database in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import?tabs=azure-powershell#using-powershell)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring a bacpac creates a new database on Azure SQL Database. Below you the PowerShell script to restore it.

```
# Restore/Import bacpac to database with an S3 performance level
$importRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $serverName `
    -DatabaseName $databaseName `
    -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "262144000" `
    -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
    -StorageKey $(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0] `
    -StorageUri "https://$storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$storageContainerName/$bacpacFilename" `
    -Edition "Standard" `
    -ServiceObjectiveName "S3" `
    -AdministratorLogin "$adminSqlLogin" `
    -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force)

# Check restore/import status and wait for the import to complete

$importStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
[Console]::Write("Importing")
while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress")
{
    $importStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
    [Console]::Write(".")
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}
[Console]::WriteLine("")
$importStatus
```

Once restored you can assign the database to an elastic pool.

```
# Move the database to the pool
$firstDatabase = Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $serverName `
    -DatabaseName $firstDatabaseName `
    -ElasticPoolName $PoolName
```